# Python Django NoReverseMatch Error When I {% url 'client_detail' client.id %}

Tags: python, html, django, hyperlink

I know my question seems fimiliar to others but it's not. I'm stuck on in the error in the below when I visit my homepage. The problem is that {% url 'client_detail' client.id %}. I'm pretty sure that I'm doing right but it's not happening.

NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'client_detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['client/(?P[0-9]+)/$']

Any help is so appreciated

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone  
from django.contrib.auth.models import User  
from django.urls import reverse

class Client(models.Model):
    client_name= models.CharField(max_length=100) 
    client_sector= models.CharField(max_length=100) 
    client_phone= models.CharField(max_length=100) 
    client_city= models.CharField(max_length=100) 
    client_district= models.CharField(max_length=100) 
    client_adress= models.TextField() 
    client_type= models.CharField(max_length=100) 
    client_priority= models.CharField(max_length=100)
    client_first_contacted_date=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Client 
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView

def ClientView(request):
    context = {'client_aranacak': Client.objects.all()}
    return render(request, 'crm/crm_home.html', context)

class ClientListView(ListView):  
    model = Client  
    template_name = 'crm/crm_home.html'  
    context_object_name = 'client_aranacak'  
    ordering = ['-client_first_contacted_date']

class ClientDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Client
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from .views import ClientListView, ClientDetailView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', ClientListView.as_view(), name='crm_client'),
    path('client/<int:pk>/', ClientDetailView.as_view(), name='client_detail'),
]

# {% url 'crm_client_detail' client.id %}
```

crm_home.html

```
{%extends "base.html"%}
{%block content%}
<div class="card mb-4">
    <div class="card-header">
        <i class="fas fa-table mr-1"></i>
        Customers
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td><strong>Client Name</strong></td>
                        <td><strong>Client Sector</strong></td>
                        <td><strong>Client Phone</strong></td>
                        <td><strong>Client City</strong></td>
                        <td><strong>Client District</strong></td>
                        <td><strong>Client Adress</strong></td>
                        <td><strong>Client Type</strong></td>
                        <td><strong>Client Priority</strong></td>
                        <td><strong>Client First Contacted Date</strong></td>
                        <td><strong>Client ID</strong></td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {%for i in client_aranacak%}
                        <tr>
                            <td><a href="{% url 'client_detail' client.id %}">{{i.client_name}}</a></td>
                            <td>{{i.client_sector}}</td>
                            <td>{{i.client_phone}}</td>
                            <td>{{i.client_city}}</td>
                            <td>{{i.client_district}}</td>
                            <td>{{i.client_adress}}</td>
                            <td>{{i.client_type}}</td>
                            <td>{{i.client_priority}}</td>
                            <td>{{i.client_first_contacted_date}}</td>
                            <td>{{i.client.id}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    {%endfor%}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{%endblock content%}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look in your `crm/crm_home.html` file and fix like :  `<td><a href="{% url 'client_detail' i.id %}">{{i.client_name}}</a></td>`

Comment: Thank you a lot barii. I really appreciated your help. That solved my for loop there. I'm such an idiot to miss it!!